# How do I access hidden or specific directories/paths from the finder?

Tags: macos, finder

I would like to be able to do something simple such as open up a finder and be able to select files that are in '~/' or '/' Is there a simple way to go about doing this?  For instance, sometimes I would just like to be able to point XCode towards a file that finder doesn't show me normally.  Is there a keystroke or something that lets me edit the path I want to view manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>⇧shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

Opens the `Go to the folder:` dialog in the Finder window:

[image]

This will let you open any folder for the directory you type.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this a lot, you can create a convenient symlink or alias to the system / hidden folder you want to access. Note that symlinks work in Terminal, aliases do not.